# c# generic types and repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

I am working on a C# MVC application using the repository pattern. I am using Unity as my IoC in order to implement my repository within the MVC application.

I have created the following generic type with the goal of minimizing code replication throughout my applications. Here is a sample:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T, C> : IDisposable,IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()


public async void AddObjectAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            // Validate that that there is not an existing object in the database.
            var x = _context.Entry(entity);
            if (!Exists(entity))
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Add(entity); // Add the entry if it does not exist.
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateObjectAsync(entity); // Update the entry if it did exist.
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

This is working great when I use a TPC or TPH strategy, however it does not play well with a TPT strategy. An Example:

```
public abstract class Component
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ComponentId { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
public class SpecialComponent : Component
{
    public string ExtraSpecialProperty { get; set; }
}
```

My implementation within the ComponentRepository:

```
public class ComponentRepository : GenericRepository<Component, HappyDbContext>, IComponentRepository
{
public async void AddComponentAsync<T>(T component) where T : class
    {
        try
        {

            if(component != null)
            {
                AddObjectAsync(component);
            }
            else
            {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteErrorLogAsync(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The first line of this code block is what I am having trouble with. In order to initialize the type GenericRepository I need to insert a class for T. In this case the DbContext C will always be the same so it is not of concern.

How can I implement a fully generic pattern that will work with inherited types? If it were a small number of items then I would be less worried about it, however that is not the case in this situation. I think that there is certainly a better way to handle this, so I am reaching out to you all for your input.

Comment: What is the relationship between the `T` parameter on the GenericRepository class and the `T` parameter on AddObjectAsync?

Comment: Would this be a situation where you could use composition over inheritance? If ComponentRepository injected a specialized factory capable of constructing GenericRepository instances, then `AddComponentAsync` could call into that factory to construct a strongly-generically-typed repository based on the type provided to that method.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. They are the same. If we pass the Entity "Component" AddObjectAsync will be of the type <Component> and expect a method parameter of (Component entity).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior 
 
That is a very interesting recommendation, I will investigate it this evening and let you know if it will work with my model. I was imaging some kind of service based approach and this may very well be the answer. If I wasn't a complete novice I could probably tell you much quicker! Thanks for the input so far.

Comment: If both `T` types are the same, then the method doesn't need this to be generic at that level. `public async void AddObjectAsync(T entity) {..}` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a case of being "over-generic".

Making the `DbContext` generic seems a waste of time if it's hard coded in 2 places. i.e. `GenericRepository<Component, HappyDbContext>` and `where C : DbContext, new()`. Strong typing the field `_context` and injecting `HappyDbContext` using Unity from the strong typed repo's might make more sense.

Also moving the generic entity type down to the method level rather than the class might simplify things as well:

```
public interface IGenericRepository
{
    void AddObjectAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ....

    public async void AddObjectAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        // Validate that that there is not an existing object in the database.
        var x = _context.Entry(entity);
        if (!Exists(entity))
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entity); // Add the entry if it does not exist.
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateObjectAsync(entity); // Update the entry if it did exist.
        }
    }
}

public interface IComponentRepository
{
    void AddComponentAsync(Component component);
    // or void AddComponentAsync<T>(T component);
    // depends if you'll be reusing the ComponentRepository 
    // for types that inherit Component but still have individual tables... 
    // It was a little difficult to tell from your example.
}

public class ComponentRepository : GenericRepository, IComponentRepository
{
    public ComponentRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) { }

    ...

    public async void AddComponentAsync(Component component)
    {
        try
        {
            if (component == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            AddObjectAsync(component);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteErrorLogAsync(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps